# Rigid boxes for snowboard and ski for air travel

Tags: air-canada, winter-sports

I'll be flying with Air Canada this winter (domestic flight in Canada) for a ski trip.

From their website, we can see

> Snowboards must be packed in a rigid and/or hard-shell case specifically designed for shipping

Does it mean we are not allowed to have ski / snowboard in a soft bag?

Note: we will be two persons, one snowboard, one pair of skis and the boots

Edit for clarification: my question was if I absolutly need a hard shell case, or they will refuse it. Someone (@DavidRicherby and @mkennedy)  answered in the comment, it  looks like it's just for insurance, lot of people travel without hard cases

Comment: You say the text you've quoted is from the airline's website. It explicitly and clearly answers your question, so I'm not sure what you're asking us.

Comment: @DavidRicherby If you google about you find a lot of people who flew on Air Canada and didn't use a hard bag.  Including one guy who was angry when he turned up the airport after shelling out $$$ for a hard case and saw lots of other people with soft cases.   In this instance I think experience trumps all

Comment: Based on the text on another section (boogie boards/skateboards), if you don't use a rigid/hard-shell case, Air Canada won't accept any liability for damage.

Answer (score -1):

From experience, I can tall you that neither me or any of my friends have ever packed boards, skis or any other gear in hard shell cases.  I don't think I've ever even seen one...we'll probably, but so few that they weren't noticeable.

What you will see by far most often is semi-rigid/rigid-back ski/board bags, canvas like material with foam inserts, [such as these](https://www.dakine.com/en-us/bags/travel-bags/ski-travel-gear-bags/).

For clarity, I don't recall any one specifically flying AC, but most of the US airlines for sure.

You will probably get a better answer somewhere where there is an AC specific forum, like a place where **flyer**s **talk** about their airlines and things...

Comment: While the general experience mentioned in the top three paragraphs is useful to know, the last sentence seems to suggest readers to look elsewhere for a better answer, which, in my opinion, diminishes the usefulness of this answer *itself, as a whole and in its current form*. I did not up/downvote as I type, as I am on the fence. It might help if you move the last paragraph to a trailing comment.

Comment: @B.Liu Yes, because the nexus of skiers who regularly fly Air Canada on this site is probably very small if even existent.  OP is more likely to find such travelers in an AC or ski related forum.  Sorry, that's just how it is.